# Xamarin Forms default contructor not found for type

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, custom-controls, xamarin.forms

I've created a custom view called PINControl, inheriting from `StackLayout`. I have used this view in my XAML like so:

```
<local:PINControl x:Name="PIN" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

In the code-behind I have this constructor:

```
public PINControl () { ... }
```

I get a `System.MissingMethodException` when the page is executing the `LoadFromXaml` method. The message is `Default constructor not found for type MyNamespace.PINControl`

I heard some talk about linkers, but setting the linker setting to *Link SDK assemblies only* it cannot build due to *The 'LinkAssemblies' task failed unexpectedly*

Some insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your inheriting from StackLayout for your custom view?  It just sounds a bit wrong, you should try inheriting from either ContentView or View for this scenario.  With regard to the MissingMethodException, do you have an empty constructor?

Comment: Goto tools ->options->Build and run -> Chose ms build outbut minimal to diaginosing..

Comment: do u have empty constructor? for this control

Comment: Could we see your entire class for `PinControl`? Or at least just including the default constructor?

Comment: @Pete I always see that custom views inherit from `View`. Why would it be wrong to inherit from `StackLayout`? That also inherits `View` right?

Comment: @HansElsen Custom views either inherit from View or ContentView.  Yes StackLayout inherits from View so there's nothing really stopping you.  I just stick to layouts being there for layout purposes only, so unless your writing your own Layout container I would just steer away from inheriting from a layout class.  It didn't appear that you was writing your own Layout container that's why I mentioned it.  Personal preference I guess.  If it works and your happy with it go ahead and use it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Damn. Xamarin disappoints me. After having Xamarin Studio restarted twice, the issue is resolved. Don't know what the actual solution was.